# Any DLL import throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError, though the DLL seems to load

Tags: java, dll, methods, import, jna

I use Eclipse Java 32Bit JDK. I am trying to import a 32-Bit DLL, which i got very few documentation for. I am using `com.sun.jna`.
The documentation tells me to call the method `InitImagerIPC` without any parameters.

As in this [example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2008/jw-02-opensourcejava-jna.html?page=2) i created an interface:

```
public interface ImagerIPC extends com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary{ 
  HRESULT InitImagerIPC ();
}
```

When I try to import the DLL no error occurs.

```
ImagerIPC lib = (ImagerIPC) Native.loadLibrary ("ImagerIPC", ImagerIPC.class);
```

But I receive an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` if I mistype my DLL name. So I guess it's loaded correctly?

But when I try to call

```
lib.InitImagerIPC();
```

I get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. :(
Where's the mistake?

BTW: The DLL Export Viewer pulls out this info for the wanted method:

```
_InitImagerIPC@0    0x10001fc0  0x00001fc0  45 (0x2d)   
    ImagerIPC.dll   J:\<my Path>\ImagerIPC.dll  Exported Function
```

I am not sure about the naming.  Do I also have to add the `_`?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace, including the full exception message.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function '_InitImagerIPC': Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

 at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:344)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:324)
 at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
 at $Proxy0._InitImagerIPC(Unknown Source)
 at main.main(main.java:13)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DLL uses the stdcall calling convention, which typically has the compiler mangle function names to include the arguments' stack size.  You need to use a `StdCallFunctionMapper` passed in as the `Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER` option when you load your library (or recompile your library to use undecorated names).

```
Library.loadLibrary("myLib", myLib.class, new HashMap() { { put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper()); } });
```